# Can I verbose output during a copy command processing?

Tags: command-line, cp

Situation: If I entered a copy command like `cp -rf /src/ /dsc/` then I am waiting several minutes for copy large directories. I forgot to put `-v` flag to verbose an output, Can I do it during copying?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No you can't, but you could use the watch command to look at the destination directory to see how the process is progressing, eg.

```
watch ls -l /dsc/
```

Comment: Please add `watch "find . | wc -l"` as well. I found it better since your command only shows one level depth.

Answer (score 126):

This question seems to be old, but for the `cp` command you've got the `--verbose` option.

So the command works as follows:

```
cp --verbose -rf /src/ /dsc/
```

Comment: someone mark this a correct answer

Comment: This is ideally what one *should* have done, but the point of the question was, what can you do to monitor the copy progress if you forgot to do this for a large operation.

Comment: on mac terminal, this gives `cp: illegal option -- -`

Comment: although `cp -rv ` works

Comment: `cp -v -r` will indicate that you want to display files being copied (as specified by `-v`), and `-r` will indicate that you want to recursively copy files, which will be needed if you are copying any sub-directories.

Answer (score 16):

You could always use `rsync` instead, you'll atleast get to see the files that are being copied

```
rsync -rva /src/ /dst/
```

Of-course this only works before you start copying as an alternative to `cp`. The good news is though that rsync will only copy the files it needs to so you can kill your long-running `cp` command run the `rsync` command and it will pick up where `cp` left off.

Answer (score 8):

I propose :

```
watch du -sh /dsc/
```

Comment: Since this is just an improvement to an existing answer, consider suggesting an [edit] instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use Midnight Commander in case when you need to see a progress of files copying.

1. Install Midnight commander:

   ```
   apt-get install mc
   ```
2. Open it:

   ```
   mc
   ```
3. On first panel open source, on second - destination. Start copying using "F5".

MC will display nice and informative progress dialog.